# Throw error in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, throw

I'm working with SQL Server 2008 R2 and I have an stored procedure where I'm trying to throw errror

```
throw 50001, 'Couldnot process,Please verify Transaction ID and EmbossLine', 1
```

But the query doesn't get executed and throws error on 50001. It was working fine on SQL Server 2012. I think there is some issue with versions. Is there anyother way I can throw error in SQL Server 2008 R2?

This is my stored procedure:

```
Alter procedure [dbo].[spGetRedemption]
    @pan varchar(19),
    @transId bigint
AS 
Begin
    if EXISTS(select * from POS_Transactions where ID=@transId) 
    Begin
       select 
           PT.ID, PT.TransactionDate, M.MerchantName1, 
           PT.TerminalID, PT.BatchNumber, PT.SequenceNumber, PT.PAN,
           C.EmbossName, PT.TotalAmount, PT.CurrencyCode, 
           TT.TransactionType, PT.InvoiceNumber 
       from 
           POS_Transactions PT
       inner join 
           Terminal T on T.TerminalID = PT.TerminalID
       inner join 
           Merchant M on M.MerchantID = T.MerchantID
       inner join 
           Card C on C.EmbossLine = PT.PAN
       inner join 
           TransactionType TT on TT.TransactionTypeID = PT.TransactionTypeID
       where 
           PT.ID = @transId
           and PT.PAN = @pan
    END
    Else
    Begin
         throw 50001, 'Couldnot process,Please verify Transaction ID and EmbossLine', 1
    END
End
```

Comment: `Throw` came in SQL 2012; `Raiserror` in 2008.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677615(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Throw` is not available in SQL Server 2008R2; it was first introduced in SQL Server 2012.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677615(v=sql.110).aspx

The alternative would be to use `Raiserror` (note; only 1 E in the middle; it's not `RaiseError`).

From the above link, there are some differences between these methods:

> **RAISERROR statement**
>
> If a msg_id is passed to RAISERROR, the ID must be defined in sys.messages.
>
> The msg_str parameter can contain printf formatting styles.
>
> The severity parameter specifies the severity of the exception.
>
> **THROW statement**
>
> The error_number parameter does not have to be defined in sys.messages.
>
> The message parameter does not accept printf style formatting.
>
> There is no severity parameter.  The exception severity is always set to 16.